# How to simply conduct statistical operations across the elements of an ArrayList<>

Tags: java, android-studio

Suppose I have the following `ArrayList<>`:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
```

The class `Person` looks like this:

```
public class Person {

String name;
int heightInCm;
int weightInKg;

// the class has the usual constructor, getters and setters

}
```

There are a variable number of instances of `Person` in `persons` (meaning `persons.size()` is not fixed).

Is there a **simple way** (i.e. using class library tools) to calculate for e.g. `heightInCm` the average value in `persons`, or determine the maximum value, or the minimum value, or ... ?

I could write some rather extensive code (using multiple loops etc.) to do the job, but surely there must be a built-in way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `persons.stream().mapToInt(p -> p.heightInCm).summaryStatistics()`

Comment: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the stream API with the [summarizingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) collector.

It will return a [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) object, containing the count, sum, min, max and average.

Example:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
IntSummaryStatistics stat = persons.stream()
                                   .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Person::getHeightInCm));
```

Comment: IntSummaryStatistics apparently (as the name suggests) is reserved for integer work. In my case, I needed floats. So I used DoubleSummaryStatistics, and casted my floats to doubles. You couldn't have known, because I used in my question for simplicity an example with integers. Thank you so much!